# Building a docker container with a 30 GB database

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a huge problem: I do have 30 GB of data that can needs to be populated into a mysql db. Every person here who wants to use this data offline (and mobile) has to import it into a local mysql db (due to different mysql versions, os and so on).

So I decided to provide a Docker container.

But now, I have problems to build the container.

1. If I try to copy the big blobs and the import-script to the container derived from a MySQL container, it theoretically works - but eats my space on the hard disk drive. First the Docker builds sends the 30GB to the docker daemon, and then the data is copied another time to the container.
2. If I try to start the `mysqld` within the container to populate the DB from the host computer I realized that Docker won't open the port 3306 during building.

So how can I populate the DB without copying the data around and around?

Is there e.g. a possibility to derive a Docker image from a (normally) running and filled container?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `volumes`

When running with `docker run` you can bind directories using `-v` flag. Example

```
-v $(pwd)/my-sql-data:/dir/in/container
```

I think this is also mentioned in official docker MySQL image on Docker Hub, check it

Comment: Can I share such a volume between Windows and Linux?

Comment: @philipp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485217/mount-current-directory-as-a-volume-in-docker-on-windows-10